# Editing Part of MySQL Table Records on a Mass Scale

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm creating a table of messages and in the actual 'message' column some records have a set phrase, so my question is, how can you change only part of a record but on a mass scale, so say I want to edit 3000 records?

For example, I may want to change the record from something like:

*I just found a really great link, take a look at it here `<b><a href="website.php">Link</a></b>`*

to

*Check out this link I just found at `<b><a href="webiste.php">Link</a></b>`*

So in other words, how do I change just the "Check out this link I just found at" part and not the actual  link?

I've tried using replace but not sure if this is right:

```
<?php
$replace_text_sql = "SELECT message REPLACE('message','I just found a really great link, take a look at it here','Check out this link I just found at') FROM posts WHERE type = 'promoted'";
$replace_text_res = mysqli_query($con, $count_posts_sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good approach for your problem [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement).
Unfortunately, I don't have a dummy DB available, where I can try it out myself, but it should work something like this for your problem:

```
UPDATE posts SET message = REPLACE (message, 'I just found...', 'Check out this...')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I've run this in my database and even though the script runs without any errors, it doesn't replace the test. I'll work on this some more

Comment: This is a working solution to this problem **BUT**, if anyone else uses this, be aware that it doesn't seem to work for words with special characters such as "I've" or "I'm"

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recomend that you look at using an [UPDATE Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

> Single-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

You also might want to look at [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str
>   replaced by the string to_str.
>
> REPLACE() performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for from_str.
>
> mysql> SELECT
>
> REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
>
> ```
>     -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com' This function is multi-byte safe.
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying Replace but it doesn't seem to work, I get Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in...